# Changing locale in karma-jasmine unit test for angularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, localization, internationalization, karma-runner

I am attempting to change locale in a Jasmine unit test for AngularJS (being run through Karma) using **angular-dynamic-local**.

```
describe('currency filter', function () {
    var currencyFilter;
    var tmhDynamicLocale;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('tmh.dynamicLocale');

        inject(function ($injector) {
            var $filter = $injector.get('$filter');
            currencyFilter = $filter('currency');
            tmhDynamicLocale = $injector.get('tmhDynamicLocale');
        });
    });

    it('formats US currency in standard form', function () {
        expect(currencyFilter(50.17)).toBe("$50.17");
    });

    it('formats French Canadian value with $ at end and comma for decimal', function () {
        tmhDynamicLocale.set('fr-ca');
        expect(currencyFilter(50.17)).toBe("50,17$");
    });
});
```

The second test fails:

```
Expected '$50.17' to be '50,17$'.
```

The locale was never changed.  The console indicates a 404 error:

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /angular/i18n/angular-locale_fr-ca.js
```

It appears that this URL path, which is recognized when running the application in the browser, is not recognized when running through Karma.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved.  We have several things going on here.

1. I was not loading the locale in **karma.conf.js**.  I had tried loading the **fr-ca** locale in **karma.conf.js** once before, but I had deleted the line because it was breaking the default (US) test. Turns out that I need to load the **en-us** locale as well (and then reset the locale in **beforeEach** as we will see in #4).

   ```
   files: [
       ...
       'bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_en-us.js',
       'bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_fr-ca.js',
       ...
   ],
   ```
2. As **martinoss** correctly stated, I needed to change the locale location pattern.  In a direct test of the currency filter, this is difficult, since there is no module on which to change **tmhDynamicLocale**'s provider.  In my real-world situation, this is not an issue, since I am testing a custom filter that is wrapping the currency filter.  For the purposes of this post, I created a brain-dead wrapper filter:

   ```
   (function() {
       angular
           .module('currencyFilterWrapper', [
               'tmh.dynamicLocale'
           ])
           .config(['tmhDynamicLocaleProvider', function(tmhDynamicLocaleProvider) {
               tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('base/bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');
   }])
           .filter('doCurrency', doCurrency)
       ;

       function doCurrency($filter) {
           return function(input) {
               return $filter('currency')(input);
           }
       }
   })();
   ```

   3. These first two items addressed the 404 problem.  But the French-Canadian locale specifies a space before the $-sign, so I changed the assertion to `expect(currencyFilter(50.17)).toBe("50,17 $");`
      But that didn't work either.  The currency filter is actually inserting a *non-breaking space*.  So the correct assertion is `expect(currencyFilter(50.17)).toBe("50,17\u00A0$");`
   4. **tmhDynamicLocale.set** is asynchronous.  Also, we need to reset the locale to the default (US) before each test.  So here is the complete spec (using Jasmine 1.3):

      ```
      describe('currency filter', function () {
          var currencyFilter;
          var tmhDynamicLocale;

          function setLocale(locale) {
              var localeSet;

              runs(function () {
                  tmhDynamicLocale.set(locale)
                      .then(function () {
                          localeSet = true;
                      });
              });

              waitsFor(function () {
                  return localeSet;
              }, 'setting locale', 100);
          }

          beforeEach(function () {
              module('currencyFilterWrapper');
              module('tmh.dynamicLocale');

              inject(function ($injector) {
                  var $filter = $injector.get('$filter');
                  currencyFilter = $filter('doCurrency');
                  tmhDynamicLocale = $injector.get('tmhDynamicLocale');
              });

              setLocale('en-us');
          });

          it('formats US currency in standard form', function () {
              expect(currencyFilter(50.17)).toBe("$50.17");
          });

          it('formats French Canadian value with $ at end and comma for decimal', function () {
              setLocale('fr-ca');

              runs(function () {
                  expect(currencyFilter(50.17)).toBe("50,17\u00A0$");
              });
          });
      });
      ```

Comment: Could you help me with a similar issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495792/angularjs-karma-404-on-locale-files-using-tmhdynamiclocaleprovider

Comment: Thanks! How did you get around the `\u00A0`? Did you just leave it like that? Doesn't look great

Answer (score 0):

This is because **angular-dynamic-locale** is loading the locale script (fr-ca in your case) when calling the set-method.
The files you add to your **karma.conf.js** are served from **/base**/angular/..., this is why you get a 404.

What you can do is to change the localeProviderPattern of thmDynamicLocaleProvider to include the base path (in the module configuration):

```
tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('base/angular/i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.  It unblocked me and got me exploring further.  My real problem was that I was not loading the locale script in **karma.conf.js**.

I had tried loading the **fr-ca** locale in **karma.conf.js** once before, but had removed the line because it was breaking the default (US) test.  The solution was the **fr-ca** locale and _then_ the **en-us** locale:
`

Comment: Oops.  It seems that I needed to set **localeLocationPattern** after all.  I'll update my answer below accordingly.