# How can I apply dynamic locale change in AngularJS tests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In an AngularJS application using `angular-dynamic-locale`, I want to test locale-dependent code in different locales.

I am trying to change the locale in an asynchronous setup. In previous Jasmine versions, this was [done with a latch function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34746832/5526862); these are now deprecated and replaced with the `done` callback.

```js
beforeEach(function (done) {
  inject(function ($injector) {
    tmhDynamicLocale = $injector.get('tmhDynamicLocale');

    console.log('setting locale to French...');
    tmhDynamicLocale
      .set('fr-fr')
      .then(function () {
        console.log('locale set.');
        done();
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        done.fail('failed to set locale:', err);
      });
  });
});
```

The promise returned by `tmhDynamicLocale.set` remains pending forever, and the setup times out.

Looking at the [innards](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale/blob/master/src/tmhDynamicLocale.js#L160) of `tmhDynamicLocale` shows that the locale change is scheduled, but never actually applied:

```js
// This line runs
$rootScope.$applyAsync(function() {
  // But this callback doesn't
  storage[storagePut](storageKey, localeId);
  $rootScope.$broadcast('$localeChangeSuccess', localeId, $locale);
  deferred.resolve($locale);
});
```

I have tried [calling `$browser.defer.flush`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10788#issuecomment-70376834) and digesting/applying the root scope, but the locale change callback is still not executed.

How can I change the locale in this test suite?

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mE9v3VOrbwz9Pfg8Y6Oh?p=preview), with logs in `tmhDynamicLocale` added for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a clean way to do it, but I've found a hackish workaround.

## Why the promise doesn't settle

`tmhDynamicLocale` [loads the locale file](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale/blob/master/src/tmhDynamicLocale.js#L49) via a `<script>` element. When the `load` event of this element fires, it [schedules](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale/blob/master/src/tmhDynamicLocale.js#L160) the `$localeChangeSuccess` event and promise resolution.

In production, this works well:

1. My code calls `tmhDynamicLocale.set('fr-fr')`
2. The `<script>` element is created
3. The locale file is loaded; `load` fires
4. In the `load` event callback, a new callback is scheduled to be applied asynchronously
5. The completed-request event also triggers an Angular digest cycle
6. The digest cycle runs the scheduled callback
7. This callback resolves the locale change promise

In tests, browser events do **not** trigger digest cycles, so this happens:

1. My code calls `tmhDynamicLocale.set('fr-fr')`
2. The `<script>` element is created
3. Any `$timeout`s in my test code run here, with an empty `$$applyAsyncQueue`
4. The locale file is loaded; `load` fires
5. In the `load` event callback, a new callback is scheduled to be applied asynchronously
6. My code is not notified of this; it has no way to trigger the new callback, and the promise pends forever

So triggering the promise resolution can't be done inside the Angular digest cycle, or at least I don't see how.

## Workaround

Since we can't tell when the callback is scheduled, poll until it is. Unlike `$interval`, `setInterval` is not mocked out in tests and allows real polling.

Once the callback is scheduled, `$browser.defer.flush` will run it, and trigger promise resolution. It throws if there are no deferred tasks to flush, so only call it if the queue is non-empty.

```
_forceFlushInterval = setInterval(function () {
  if ($rootScope.$$applyAsyncQueue.length > 0) {
    $browser.defer.flush();
  }
});
```

Conceivably, tasks other than the locale change could be scheduled. So we keep polling until the promise is settled.

```
tmhDynamicLocale.set('fr-fr')
  .then(function () {
    clearInterval(_forceFlushInterval);
    done();
  })
  .catch(function () {
    clearInterval(_forceFlushInterval);
    done.fail();
  });
```

But there are many drawbacks:

1. Accessing $$private Angular internals is not a good idea, and is likely to break between versions.
2. Constantly flushing may interfere with other asynchronous setup.
3. If for some reason the interval doesn't get cleared, it will wreak all kinds of havoc on later tests.

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/I5OvyM4PzMIJjiAt1pcD?p=preview)**